# Problems with adding social_django to wagtail

Tags: django, google-authentication, wagtail

I added this url in /projectname/urls.py:

```
url(r'social-auth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
```

And then I added this in my wagtail homepage template (as shown in [docs example](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/blob/master/example/example/templates/home.html)):

```
   {% for name in social_auth.backends.oauth %}
      <li><a rel="nofollow" href="{% url "socialauth_begin" %}">{{ name|title }}</a></li>
   {% endfor %}
```

But i saw nothing in template, but I have added

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
 'social_core.backends.open_id.OpenIdAuth',  # for Google authentication
 'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOpenId',  # for Google authentication
 'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',  # for Google authentication
 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

in settings/base.py.

So how can I implement authentication in wagtail CMS, so users can add comments to blog?

EDIT:

Thats how my TEMPLATES setting look:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
                'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_by_type_backends',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

And my homepage now shows error:

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 106, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 169, in render
    with context.bind_template(self):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 242, in bind_template
    processors = (template.engine.template_context_processors +
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 85, in template_context_processors
    return tuple(import_string(path) for path in context_processors)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 85, in <genexpr>
    return tuple(import_string(path) for path in context_processors)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'social_auth'
[26/Jun/2019 15:04:39] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 124661
^[[15~Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 106, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 169, in render
    with context.bind_template(self):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 242, in bind_template
    processors = (template.engine.template_context_processors +
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 85, in template_context_processors
    return tuple(import_string(path) for path in context_processors)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 85, in <genexpr>
    return tuple(import_string(path) for path in context_processors)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'social_auth'
[26/Jun/2019 15:04:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 124661
```

Comment: Please give the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: Yeah, i added it

Answer (score 1):

The variable `social_auth` is defined by a template context processor:
https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/blob/master/doc/configuration.rst#template-context-processors

It appears that the example app is [using `'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_by_type_backends'`](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/blob/master/example/example/settings.py#L167), so you should probably add that to your project's `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how TEMPLATES setting looks. But, my homepage now shows new error (also in eddited answer)